# Highlight words in excel in c# windows

Tags: c#, windows, excel, highlight

Am using the below code to highlight specific words in excel. The search words are in an xml file. Am taking all the words in a cell into a string and am splitting them to compare it with search words. So if a word is "can" then the cell containing can gets highlighted. But the problem is when the word is "Can Be" then its getting splitted and not highlighting. Is there any way to come over this problem.

```
try
{
    string[] arr = XDocument.Load(xmlSource).Descendants(nodeString)
     .Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();

    string str;
    int rCnt = 0;
    int cCnt = 0;
    for (int x = 1; x <= count; x++)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet4;
        Excel.Range range;
        xlWorkSheet4 = (Excel.Worksheet)doc2.Worksheets.get_Item(x);
        Excel.Range last3 = xlWorkSheet4.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
        range = xlWorkSheet4.get_Range("A1", last3);
        for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
        {
            for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
            {
                if (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt].Value2 is string)
                {
                    str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                    if (str == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("null");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        str.Replace("\\", "");
                        string[] words = str.Split(' ');
                        foreach (string arrs in arr)
                        {
                            foreach (string word in words)
                            {
                                if (word == arrs)
                                {

                                    var cell = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range);

                                    cell.Font.Bold = 1;
                                    cell.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("not string");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you do some formatting

Comment: Maybe the actual answer you are looking for is simply in the comparison part? word.Contains(arrs) ?

Comment: @Kyle ... I can :) there you go ... readable

Comment: even this doesnt work. if the string is"my name is" and search word is "me" "then my na"me" is" is getting highlighted. But i want to search wholeword

Comment: sry Eugene..it worked.Thanku

Answer (score 0):

```
     for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
          {
             for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
                 {
                    if (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt].Value2 is string)
                       {
                          str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                          if (str == null)
                          {
                            Console.WriteLine("null");
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            // str.Replace("\\", "");
                            //  string[] words = str.Split(' ');
                            foreach (string arrs in arr)
                            {
                               if (str.Contains(arrs))
                               {
                                 //foreach (string word in words)
                                 //{
                                 //    if (word == arrs)
                                 //    {
                                 var cell = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range);
                                 cell.Font.Bold = 1;
                                 cell.Font.Color= System.Drawing.ColorTranslator
                                                  .ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

                                       }

                               }
                           //  }
                             //}
                     }
 }
```